# Cerrar conexiones en PHP con base de datos PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql

Buen día, actualmente presento un problema al momento de cerrar conexiones `PostgreSQL`, con `MySQL` no presentaba el problema y se cerraba la conexión fácilmente tan solo usando `mysqli_close($conexion)` investigando un poco para cerrar conexiones con `PostgreSQL` seria tan fácil como `pg_close($conexion)` sin embargo obtengo el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: pg_close(): Argument #1 ($connection) must be of type resource or null, PDO given in

Y en la documentacion de `PHP` no hay nada mas que agregar:

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pg-close.php

Sintaxis de mi script php:

```
<?php

//Inicializo la conexion mediante funciones
include('conexion.php');
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

$id_categoria=$_GET['id_categoria'];

//Ejecuto la consulta
$sql = "select id_producto, nombre, precio_vta from inv_productos where 
id_categoria = '$id_categoria'";

$query = $conexion->query($sql);

$datos = array();

if($id_categoria > 0){

while($resultado = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
  }
}

//Imprimo el resultado
echo json_encode(array("Productos" => $datos));

//Cierro la conexión
pg_close($conexion);

?>
```

Cual es el problema? o hay alguna alternativa para cerrar conexiones? espero me puedan ayudar si necesitan el código completo del script en `PHP` por favor decirme, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el código donde inicializas la conexión y donde tratas de cerrarla? El error te está diciendo que a la función le estás pasando un PDO, un objeto, en lugar de una variable de tipo resource.

Comment: Hola @RubioRic ya he agregado la sintaxis completa tomando de ejemplo una consulta para obtener registros

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que devuelve $objeto->Conectar()?

Comment: Échale un ojo al ejemplo #3. Creo que puede ser tu caso. Aunque en el enlace aparece MySql, ten en cuenta que ahí y en tu caso se accede a la BD a través de PDO https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Hola @RubioRic comentarte que efectivamente me ha funcionado el ejemplo, muchas gracias!

Comment: No hay de que :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te apuntaba en los comentarios, el mensaje de error es bastante informativo. Te está indicando que el tipo que espera como argumento la función `pg_close` es resource y tú le estás pasando un `PDO` (PHP Data Object).

Si buscamos en Google en inglés cómo cerrar una conexión PDO encontraremos entre los primeros resultados [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277233/pdo-closing-connection) de nuestro foro hermano, [cuya respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18277327/2553194) nos remite a la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php).

> The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To
> close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that
> all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning
> NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this
> explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your
> script ends.

Que en español han traducido como

> La conexión permanecerá activa durante el tiempo de vida del objeto
> PDO. Para cerrar la conexión, es necesario destruir el objeto
> asegurándose de que todas las referencias a él existentes sean
> eliminadas; esto se puede hacer asignando null a la variable que
> contiene el objeto. Si no se realiza explícitamente, PHP cerrará
> automáticamente la conexión cuando el script finalice.

Justo a continuación de este párrafo en la mencionada documentación podemos encontrar un ejemplo de cierre de conexión que coincide con lo que tú estás buscando

```
<?php
$mbd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);
// Utilizar la conexión aquí
$sth = $mbd->query('SELECT * FROM foo');

// Ya se ha terminado; se cierra
$sth = null;
$mbd = null;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas mezclando peras con manzanas.
Hablamos de dos extensiones diferentes para conectarse a la base de datos:

- [PostgreSQL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pgsql.php). Específica, para PostgreSQL.
- [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php). Abstracta, que soporta varios motores de base de datos, entre ellos PostgreSQL.

Para cerrar la conexión con `pg_close` debiste abrirla con `pg_connect`.

Si usas PDO, basta con asignarle `null` al objeto y a los recursos previamente utilizados; aunque eso se hace automáticamente al finalizar la ejecución del script; además, el manual indica:

> Muchas aplicaciones web se beneficiarán del uso de [conexiones persistentes](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php#example-958) a servidores de bases de datos. Las conexiones persistentes no son cerradas al final del script

En otras palabras, no tiene mucho caso que cierres la conexión.